How to know what version of Share/Docker to use for my version of Alfresco?
First post on stack overflow, so I may do something wrong here, if so I'm sorry.
I'm new to both Alfresco and Docker, and not very experienced with maven either. I am currently setting up a default all-in-one project via maven. The project downloaded is set on Alfresco 23.x, so I tried configuring the main pom.xml file to make the project correspond to my needs (namely "using Alfresco 7.x"), so I put the most recent version (I believe), 7.4.2, as well as SDK 4.8.0. Not entirely sure whether they're actually the most recent versions here though (besides SDK 5;X and Alfresco 23.x, I mean).
My issue right now is that I don't know what to put for alfresco.share.version and alfresco.share.docker.version in my pom.xml. But beyond the required Version number itself, I'd like to be able to find it myself the next time I need to set it up, so I'd like an explanation of how to find it myself.
This is an extract of the relevant part of my main (the parent project's) pom.xml file:
        <alfresco.sdk.version>4.8.0</alfresco.sdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Properties used in dependency declarations, you don't need to
        change these -->
        <alfresco.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.groupId>
        <alfresco.bomDependencyArtifactId>acs-community-packaging</alfresco.bomDependencyArtifactId>
        <alfresco.platform.version>7.4.2</alfresco.platform.version>
        <alfresco.platform.docker.user>alfresco</alfresco.platform.docker.user>
        <alfresco.share.version>???</alfresco.share.version>
        <alfresco.share.docker.version>???</alfresco.share.docker.version>

I heard these two are supposed to be the version of their own thing, so they apparently aren't supposed to be exactly alfresco's version number BUT I can't find the explanation on how to find what version of share works with what version of alfresco, nor what version of share.docker to use with that...
I tried building multiple times with different combinations of version numbers I found everywhere online, but nothing lets me build, saying the dependency could not be found or is incompatible, stuff like that.
Could anyone please explain to me how I can find the corresponding version numbers for those three parameters? (and what other changes I may need to do on this pom.xml file if I did something wrong...)
Thank you in advance.

I guess the best approach is to create a project for SDK 4.6.0 (the one corresponding to ACS 7.4.x)
When creating a sample project like that, I'm getting following values:
<alfresco.sdk.version>4.6.0</alfresco.sdk.version>
<alfresco.platform.version>7.4.0.1</alfresco.platform.version>
<alfresco.platform.docker.user>alfresco</alfresco.platform.docker.user>
<alfresco.share.version>20.165</alfresco.share.version>
<alfresco.share.docker.version>7.4.0.1</alfresco.share.docker.version>

If you want to use a specific version of Alfresco Share (like 7.4.2), then you need to find the right number for "alfresco.share.version":
https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-community-packaging/blob/7.4.2/pom.xml#L17
That is 22.17 in this case.
